# How can I customize my <ul> so it doesn't effect other bullets on my page?

Tags: css, header

I am trying to incorporate this code that I got for a header on my page, however it changes all of the bullets on the rest of the site to follow the assigned rules. How can I define this so that the rules ONLY apply to this menu?

```css
<style>
/* do not change */
.container{
overflow: unset; 
}
ul{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
display:inline-block;
}
ul li ul li{
display:none;
}
/* can change */
#container{
text-align:center;
}
ul li{
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid green;
width:130px;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
margin:5px;
border-radius:25px;
}
ul li a{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
display: block;
}
ul li a:hover{
background-color:red;
text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:25px;
  color:white;
}
ul li:hover ul li{
display:block;
margin-left:0px;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li><a href='#scroll-section1'>Monkeys</a></li>
<li><a href='#scroll-section2'>Option 1</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href='#scroll-section2'>Option a</a></li>
      <li><a href='https://www.amarketingessentials.com'>Option b</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#scroll-section3'>Option 2</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Option 3</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Option 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This has been very frustrating so far. I am not a coder, so trying to self problem solve this has been trial-and-error with no positive results. For reference this code is being inserted into my Clickfunnels page.

Comment: use the id you have . Select your ul/li from there : `#container ul {}`  Do this for every selector you have here for that peticular ul .

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id to your  tag:

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li><a href='#scroll-section2'>Option a</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.amarketingessentials.com'>Option b</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then just call that id in your CSS:

```css
#mylist {
  /* styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to study the HTML classes (see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp). Directly adding the element (ul, li, h1, p, ecc..) in your CSS will modify all the occurrences of that element in the page. Creating a class and assigning it only to the desired element will affect only that element